# Can I frame text in a plot to look like legend?

Tags: legending, text, labeling

I have a `DateListPlot`, much the same as below, that I want to overlay text onto.
I'd like the text to be wrapped in a frame much the same way as the legend box is, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I've tried the cheaters way of putting a rectangle beneath the text, but then I can't get the rounded corners to match the legend box. I am also unable to changed the thickness of the legend frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DateListPlot[{FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2008"], 
  FinancialData["GOOG", "Jan. 1, 2008"]}, Joined -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> .3, FrameLabel -> {None, "Price"},
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Several\nLines\nof Text", 12], 
    Scaled[{0.02, .5}], {-1, 0}, 
    Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, .8]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"IBM", "GOOGLE"}, LabelStyle -> 12, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.05]], RoundingRadius -> 4, 
        Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, .8]] &)], {{.98, .95}, {1, 
     1}}]]
```

[image: CurrentPlot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Framed.html) together with [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html?q=Inset&lang=en).

```
DateListPlot[{FinancialData["GOOG", "Jan. 1, 2008"]}, Joined -> False,
  ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> .3, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, "Price"}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Framed[Text[Style["Several\nLines\nof Text", 12]], 
     RoundingRadius -> 4, Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, .8]], 
    Scaled[{0.06, .5}]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"IBM", "GOOGLE"}, LabelStyle -> 12, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.05]], RoundingRadius -> 4, 
        Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 1, .8]] &)], {{.98, .95}, {1, 
     1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to change the thickness of the frame?  When I export to pdf, it is much thicker than the plot frame. `Inset` works beautifully, BTW.

Comment: @ChrisRoth Since the obvious `Framed[x + y, FrameStyle -> Thin]` does not work I don't have any ideas. You could either use the second answer or perhaps rasterize the plot before exporting to PDF (It looks fine as an image)

Comment: Try `AbsoluteThickness` for the frame thickness specification.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Does not work (since the frame is not a graphics directive).

Comment: @ChrisRoth Hmm, perhaps this issue should/could be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

`Rectangle` has an `Option` `RoundingRadius`:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 100], 
         Epilog -> {
           {EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[.5], Orange, 
            Rectangle[Scaled[{.6, .4}], Scaled[{.9, .9}], RoundingRadius -> Scaled@.02]},
           {Black, Text[Style["Fake\nlegend", 18], Scaled[{.75, .65}]]}}]
```

[image]